# HREF links are not working inside of an accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

When I am trying to click the link, then accordion is not working. Below is my content page link.

```
<script src="accordion/jquery.accordion.source.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In master page I have used below script link.

```
<link href="accordion/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="accordion/dependencies/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="accordion/jquery.accordion.source.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

ASP.NET HTML design:

```
  <ul class="accordion">
  <li><a href="#one">example1</a>
  <div>....</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#two">example2</a>
  <div>....</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#three">example3</a>
  <div>....</div>
  </li>
  </ul>


  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('ul').accordion();
   });

 </script>
```

Comment: Try to put your scripts before the end of the body element :)

Comment: I am using script into content page, here we will not use any <body></body>. @PDKnight

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, I can't help you here then :/

Comment: Please give me any suggestion. @PDKnight

Comment: I'm not actually working with ASP .NET...can you put jQuery and accordion before your own script http://prntscr.com/9l5t90? If yes, try it :)

Comment: ya i did not working @PDKnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't work because you **didn't import jQuery UI**.

## [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/boqomotoso/edit?html,output)

```
<ul class="accordion">
  <li><a href="#one">example1</a>
    <div>....</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#two">example2</a>
    <div>....</div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#three">example3</a>
    <div>....</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $( ".accordion" ).accordion();
</script>
```